# How can I buy the tiki armor and accessories?

Tags: terraria

I badly want to buy the tiki armor, necklace, and Hercules beetle so that I can turn my one pygmy into six buff ones. However, my witch doctor refuses to sell them! I have built him a home in the jungle, and tried another in the underground jungle. I have tried at all times of day. I have defeated Plantera (solo and MP) and possess both the temple key, and the pygmy staff (2, in fact) what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug, and is in the list of bugfixes for the next version.

Bug now fixed. :)

Comment: Where might one see that list?

Comment: here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RAMONXCb_JsXHgxyCCXCKcS7fSr7nLJgmb6RW8Ux-0M/preview?sle=true